# angular 2 using 'onended' audio event emitter with Component local member

Tags: javascript, html, angular, audio

Can anyone help me around with how I use `audio.onended()` to play next song in the playlist?
I can add songs to the playlist and even play a song with the above method by passing an `audioObject`. However, when `audio.onended` fires, it says `this.playlist.item is undefined`.

It's something to do with the scope I think.
Is there another way around for firing `ended()` and interact with a member variable of this class?

```js
export class ..... {

   playlist = {
       item: []
   };



   playMedia(audioObject) {
       this.nowPlayingChange.next(audioObject);
       if (this.audio) {
           this.audio.src = '';
           this.audio.load();
       }
       this.audio = new Audio();
       this.audio.src = audioObject.src;
       this.audio.type = 'audio/mp3';
       this.audio.load();
       if (!this.audio.error) {
           this.audio.play();
       }
       this.audio.onended = function() {
           if (this.playlist.item.length > 1) {
               for (let i = 0; i < this.playlist.item.length; i++) {
                   if (audioObject.title === this.playlist.item[i].title) {
                       if (i !== (this.playlist.item.length - 1))
                           this.playMedia(this.playlist[i + 1]);
                   } else {
                       this.audio.pause();
                   }
               }
           } else {
               this.audio.pause();
           }
       };
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use the arrow function `=>` instead of `function` to preserve `this` keyword :

```
this.audio.onended = () => {         
              if(this.playlist.item.length > 1) {
              for (let i = 0; i < this.playlist.item.length; i++) {
                if (audioObject.title === this.playlist.item[i].title) {
                  if(i !== (this.playlist.item.length - 1))
                  this.playMedia(this.playlist[i+1]);
                } else 
                {
                  this.audio.pause();
                }
              }
            } else {
              this.audio.pause();
            }
            };
```

Comment: moreover, I realized if you need to fire more than one logic, its good to wrap all logic in a method and invoke it inside onended() scope. this.audio.onended()=>{this.logics();} logics() {...do something}